# Google AppsScript server error on getFiles()

Tags: google-apps-script, runtime-error

Getting a server error on

var contents = folder.getFiles(1501,500);

Ran fine for the first three iterations, 0,500 and 501,500 and 1001,500.  There are over 3,000 files in the folder.  Clicked it many times over the last several hours. Would anything else cause the error?

Also how are files added to a folder.  If I add files can I get the increment by looking at the end of the list or the beginning?

Just played with the 500, reducing it and I got it to run a few more times, 1900 files total and it stopped again.  Is there some limit on the max number.  Looks like no more than 1999 files.  Is this true?  Guess I have to split the directory.

Comment: You could try using the [get files for paging]( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_token)

Comment: Also, you could check out [yesterday's error](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2477) re DocsList, but I can't say that it is related.

Comment: Lastly, within the last 2 hours, this WAS working for me, successfully fetching 3000 files:  var result = DocsList.findForPaging(' my words to find in the file ', pageSize, token);         But this next one was NOT working for me (i.e. it did not page beyond 200 files) var result = DocsList.getFilesByTypeForPaging(DocsList.FileType.DOCUMENT, pageSize, token);